# how to get data for particular period in apache solr

Tags: solr

i want to get record for a period in solr

my url is

```
http://localhost:8090/solr/select?q=xyz=Vehicles per KM of record Road&version=2.2&start=0&rows=200&indent=on&omitHeader=true&wt=json&sort=timestamp desc
```

and my response is

```
{
    "response": {
        "numFound": 4,
        "start": 0,
        "docs": [
            {                
                 "xyz": "some record one",
                 "ids": "an22f17b87-3c75-4b77-9300-9039a9fe63f2", 
                 "timestamp": "2014-11-07T10:41:29.544Z",
                 "id": [
                    "e1d1865-1402-ef20-6880-9262d6e7d22"
                 ]
            },
            {                
                 "xyz": "some record two", 
                 "ids": "an22f17b87-3c75-4b77-9300-9039a9fe63f2",
                 "timestamp": "2014-11-06T10:34:53.799Z",
                 "id": [
                    "99eab5aa-c83b-e90b-e548-6d09e94c9ba2"
                ]
            },
            {                
                "xyz": "some record three",              
                "ids": "an22f17b87-3c75-4b77-9300-9039a9fe63f2",
                "timestamp": "2014-11-03T09:05:45.521Z",
                "id": [
                    "84fba82a-2ae6-eaa8-1b37-79c842c9e96"
                ]
            },
            {                
                "xyz": "some record four",              
                "ids": "an22f17b87-3c75-4b77-9300-9039a9fe63f2",
                "timestamp": "2014-11-01T09:05:45.521Z",
                "id": [
                    "84fba82a-2ae6-eaa8-1b37-79c842c9e96"
                ]
            }

        ]
    }
}
```

> I am getting some problems

1.in my search query sentence is "Vehicles per KM of record Road".
but am getting records which doesn't have.

it suppose to come one record only

```
 {                
                "xyz": "Vehicles per KM of record Road",              
                "ids": "an22f17b87-3c75-4b77-9300-9039a9fe63f2",
                "timestamp": "2014-11-01T09:05:45.521Z",
                "id": [
                    "84fba82a-2ae6-eaa8-1b37-79c842c9e96"
                ]
            }
```

2.I want to get records for particular periods 
example from 2014-11-08 to 2014-11-05

in this case only two records should come

```
  {                
                 "xyz": "some record one",
                 "ids": "an22f17b87-3c75-4b77-9300-9039a9fe63f2", 
                 "timestamp": "2014-11-07",
                 "id": [
                    "e1d1865-1402-ef20-6880-9262d6e7d22"
                 ]
            },
            {                
                 "xyz": "some record two", 
                 "ids": "an22f17b87-3c75-4b77-9300-9039a9fe63f2",
                 "timestamp": "2014-11-06",
                 "id": [
                    "99eab5aa-c83b-e90b-e548-6d09e94c9ba2"
                ]
            }
```

but i am getting all records
please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the field types, the second question should be a date interval filter (as long as it's date field .. although it would probably work with string fields as well):

```
timestamp:[2014-11-05 TO 2014-11-09]
```

You might have to tweak those values to get the correct cut off (but I think 11-09 should be 2014-11-09 00:00:00, meaning that only entries from earlier than that date should be included).

For the first part, it depends on your query parser. If the parser is `dismax`, the `mm` clause and the default boolean operator will determine how the search is done. You do not want `xyz=` there, unless it's part of the data you're searching for (searching in a specific field would be `field:`).

Use the analysis page in Solr administration to see why you're not matching what you're looking for (enter the content indexed and the search string, which should give you a more detailed view of what Solr is doing internally for each step).